# ¿Cómo puedo realizar cache de imágenes u otros archivos?

Tags: javascript, http, cache

Conozco que puedo realizar el proceso con `LocalStorage` o `SessionStorage` para ciertas cosas, pero la verdad no he visto algún ejemplo muy claro de si puedo cachear todas las imágenes de [toncandigital.com](http://toncandigital.com) o los archivos `css` para que pueda disminuir más la velocidad del sitio mientras el usuario navega por las distintas páginas.

No sé si puedo hacer algo como

```
var image = document.getElementByTagName("img");

localStorage.setItem("Imagen", image);
```

y así guardar los datos de las imagenes en el localStorage. No lo tengo del todo claro, si alguien pudiera ayudarme con eso. Lo agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Si lo que quieres es "cachear" para ganar velocidad deberías usar headers en lugar del localStorage. De preferencia [`ETag`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) o expires, lee http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html y https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields. Esto tienes que implementarlo en tu servidor (Quizás ya se hace automático si sirves recursos estáticos como imágenes).

Comment: Consulta también http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios chicos, revisaré los enlaces que me dejaron para ver como puedo implementarlo. Aunque de todas formas me hubiese gustado saber si era posible hacerlo por localStorage, más que nada para aprender también xD

Comment: Como verás en los enlaces y como te puse en los otros comentarios si lo que quieres es **performance** entonces localStorage no te sirve pues tiene muy poca capacidad (5 Mb) y no estás usando las herramientas del navegador. Básicamente cuando usas headers le estás pidiendo ayuda al navegador para realizar las tareas y el es muy bueno en ese aspecto

Comment: ok @devconcept muchas gracias de nuevo por la respuesta. Revisaré todo bien entonces :P

Answer (score 0):

Siempre y cuando estés trabajando con HTML5 puede hacer el uso del manejo del caché que se define en esta especificación.

Puedes revisar la propiedad manifest de la etiqueta HTML de la página. Acá puedes ver el detalle de lo que te estoy mencionando:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Recursos_offline_en_firefox

Espero te sirva y sea lo que estás buscando.

Comment: El primer enlace no funciona. Por favor, haz un pequeño resumen/guía de lo que encontrará en el enlace por si éste deja de ser válido.