# Como saber si guarda cache?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que mi última modificación de un archivo fué a las 17:50 PM , luego el usuario entra pero sigue viendo la página como si aún no se actualizara y  no le carga correctamente, como puedo verificar con javascript si tiene la última version de algún archivo específico?

Comment: Falta indicar lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Referencia [ask].

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22201/65

Answer (score 0):

Para segurarte que siempre cargue la ultima versión y evitar cache, puedes agregarle un parametro al query string de la ruta del archivo asi:

```
<script src="hosting/mi_archivo.js?version=1.0" />
```

Siempre que modiques el archivo le cambias la version la ruta y listo. Esto forza al navegador a que siempre que el valor version cambie cargue el archivo. El valor puede ser cualquier cosa siempre y cuando lo actualizes cuando hagas un cambio al archivo.

Asi siempre sabras que version es y que siempre tendra la ultima actualizacion.

Comment: Podrías darme algo de documentación por favor

Comment: http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-content-prep/preventing-browser-cache.php, https://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache. En ingles

Comment: Ya [existe una pregunta duplicada aqui mismo en es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63716/como-evitar-el-cach%C3%A9-de-los-archivos-css-y-js) mas extensa que mi respuesta.